# Can't update mysql without system root password set

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, mysql, password

I am trying to update the system but mysql 5.7 is failing. It appears that it cannot connect due to authentication issues.

Here is the full console output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server-5.7 is already the newest version (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Important bit:

```
 mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I can login just fine with "mysql -u root -p" command. I don't use a password to login to the server as I use ssh keys if it matters.

Why did this issue crop up now and what can be done to resolve it? I also haven't updated the system in quite a while but this is the only package with issues.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to enable passwordless login to mySQL via Unix Socket which is usually enabled by default, but maybe you have changed that.

Login to `mysql` root shell and run this:

```
grant usage on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified via unix_socket;
```

---

If this doesn't work, try to add a file `~/.my.cnf` with content:

```
[client]
user=root
password=your_password
```

make it readable only by the owner (and root):

```
chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf
```

and then try again.

Comment: I am getting syntax error, syntax checker points to "via unix_socket" as the issue. Is it valid syntax for mysql 5.7?

Comment: Second method also results in the same error as in the original question.